# Textbook on Cryptography

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

I am proposing (and will be teaching next year) a new math elective on Cryptography in our curriculum here at Illinois State University. In addition to standard topics including RSA public key and elliptic curve cryptography the course will introduce other cyrptographic protocols such as digital signatures, oblivious transfers, Zero-knowledge proofs, coin tossing over telephone and Yao's Millionaires' problem. I was thinking of using Koblitz's book "A course in Number Theory and Cryptography" but I would like to know if there are some modern textbooks out there which will cover some of these topics. Any book recommendations for this course will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest the following book http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441926746

Comment: This one may be helpful http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642321658

Comment: Another option: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Cryptography-Coding-Theory-2nd/dp/0131862391. Although in a fast-moving applied area like crypto, note the publication date compared with the suggestion by @Amin235.

Comment: http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/~dstinson/CTAP3/CTAP3.html

Comment: Hello, did you find a good source? Because we are also going to offer a similar university elective course and I need to find a textbook which is suitable for the students in colleges of science, engineering, and economy, with minimum knowledge of mathematics.